# How to Implement Spring Boot controller that can accept a batch of records?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ndjson

I'm currently working on a Spring Boot application where I need to create a service endpoint similar to the one mentioned in the Confluent Cloud documentation ([link](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/kafka-rest/kafka-rest-cc.html#producing-a-batch-of-records-to-a-topic)).

The cURL example provided in the documentation is as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H  \
"Authorization: Basic <BASE64-encoded-key-and-secret>” \
"https://<REST-endpoint>/kafka/v3/clusters/<cluster-id>/topics/<topic-name>/records" -d \
'{"value": {"type": "BINARY", "data": "<base64-encoded-data>"}} {"value": {"type": "BINARY", "data": "<base64-encoded-data>"}}'
```

Could anyone guide me on how to create the Spring Boot controller that can accept a batch of records and effectively access the data from within the controller?

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What did you try? Seems straightforward.

Comment: I tried ndjson as well with no luck. This is not a JSON array. It is a concatenated JSON payload.

Comment: I tried ndjson as well with no luck. This is not a JSON array. It is a concatenated JSON payload.